# When would a UUID variant be an integer?

Tags: python, uuid

The [documentation on the `uuid` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html) says:

> `UUID.`**`variant`** [¶](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID.variant)
>
> The UUID variant, which determines the internal
> layout of the UUID. This will be one of the integer constants
> [RESERVED_NCS](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html#uuid.RESERVED_NCS),
> [RFC_4122](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html#uuid.RFC_4122),
> [RESERVED_MICROSOFT](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html#uuid.RESERVED_MICROSOFT),
> or
> [RESERVED_FUTURE](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html#uuid.RESERVED_FUTURE).

And later:

> `uuid.`**`RESERVED_NCS`** [¶](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html#uuid.RESERVED_NCS)
>
> Reserved for NCS compatibility.
>
> `uuid.`**`RFC_4122`** [¶](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html#uuid.RFC_4122)
>
> Specifies the UUID layout given in [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html).
>
> `uuid.`**`RESERVED_MICROSOFT`** [¶](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html#uuid.RESERVED_MICROSOFT)
>
> Reserved for Microsoft compatibility.
>
> `uuid.`**`RESERVED_FUTURE`** [¶](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html#uuid.RESERVED_FUTURE)
>
> Reserved for future definition.

Given this, I expected to see integers when accessing these attributes. However:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> u = uuid.uuid4()
>>> u.variant
'specified in RFC 4122'
>>> uuid.RESERVED_NCS
'reserved for NCS compatibility'
>>> uuid.RFC_4122
'specified in RFC 4122'
>>> uuid.RESERVED_MICROSOFT
'reserved for Microsoft compatibility'
>>> uuid.RESERVED_FUTURE
'reserved for future definition'
```

This produces the same result in 2.7.9 and 3.4.2, and I haven't found documentation for any version that suggests that these constants might be strings.

The most relevant search results I could produce on this issue happen to be the source code for this module (on [SVN](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/uuid.py) or [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/uuid.py)), which contains this statement:

> ```
> RESERVED_NCS, RFC_4122, RESERVED_MICROSOFT, RESERVED_FUTURE = [
> ```

```
    'reserved for NCS compatibility', 'specified in RFC 4122',
    'reserved for Microsoft compatibility', 'reserved for future definition']
```

Given the results I saw in the interpreter, this makes perfect sense, but I can't say the same for the documentation.

Is this a simple documentation bug, or is there someplace where these attributes would indeed be integers, as the documentation promises? What's going on here?

Comment: I would guess the constants were changed from integers to strings at some point in the past without updating the documentation. My Mercurial skills aren't quite up to confirming that tonight, though.

Comment: @chepner - Looking at GitHub, the [August 21, 2006 commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/a9c343d0c354e0aa41674f5c84a5dc28241c7a0c) has a [uuid.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a9c343d0c354e0aa41674f5c84a5dc28241c7a0c/Lib/uuid.py) with the same list of variant string constants it has today, and that repo doesn't go back any further.

Comment: It seems like a doc bug, the original appearance of this in the Python 2.5 branch on Github shows it always has been like this. Did you file a bug on the tracker to get this looked at?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard - This module was released along with its documentation in 2.5, described [in this tracker issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue1508766). However, the [attached file](https://bugs.python.org/file7336/libuuid.tex) doesn't mention any integer constants, which is odd because the [2.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-uuid.html) has the exact same wording we see in today's documentation. I guess I'll see about filing a bug on the tracker.

Comment: [Issue opened.](http://bugs.python.org/issue29217)

Comment: Glad to see it got fixed (and quick!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in the documentation. I submitted it as such in the [official bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue29217), and it has been fixed by removing the word "integer":

> I simply remove the type description since I think the type of the constants doesn't matter here.